# Interpretation of a version of the Binomial Coefficient with double factorial

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, factorial, gamma-function

Let $n_1, n_2$ be two positive integers. It is well known that the binomial coefficient,
$$
\frac{(n_1+n_2)!}{n_1! \, \,  n_2!}
$$
represents the number of possible choices of $n_1$ elements from a set containing $n_1+n_2$ elements.

Moreover, it is well known that, if $n$ is an even integer, then $(n-1)!!$ can be interpreted as the number ways the elements of the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ can be divided into $n/2$ pairs.

Do
$$
\frac{(n_1+n_2-1)!!}{(n_1-1)!!(n_2-1)!!},
$$
or
$$
\frac{(n_1+n_2-2)!!}{(n_1-1)!!(n_2-1)!!},
$$
which combines the two formulas above, have some combinatorial interpretation, similarly to the two quantities which have been introduced above?

Comment: The coefficients you suggest are not necessarily integers so I doubt they have much significance.

Comment: Shouldn't $(2n-1)!!$ say $(n-1)!!$?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm Try typing in DFBC(n,m) into Wolfram Alpha.